# Autenticação - Current.User.Identity retornando null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Meu login

```
 Dim senha = "null"
    If Not (senhaLogin.Text = "") Then
        senha = senhaLogin.Text
    End If
    Dim Usuario = GetUsuario.Where(Function(a) a.Email = emailLogin.Text And a.Senha = senha)
    If Usuario.Count > 0 Then
        Dim userName = Usuario.FirstOrDefault().ID
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, False)
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
    End If
```

Minha validação que verifica se o usuario está autenticado

```
Dim ID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
If ID.Name = "" Then
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
End If
```

Meu problema é que sempre recebo o `ID.Name` como null.

Comment: No seu método Usuario.FirstOrDefault().ID está retornando alguma coisa? Porque fiz aqui em C#, práticamente igual e funcionou. Na minha opnião acho que se você retirar .FirstOrDefault() e colocar só Usuario.ID vai funcionar.

Comment: Seu usuário existe mesmo? Seu método GetUsuario está retornando alguma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta:

```
Dim senha = Nothing
If Not (senhaLogin.Text = "") Then senha = senhaLogin.Text
Dim Usuario = GetUsuario.Where(Function(a) a.Email = emailLogin.Text : a.Senha = senha)
If Usuario.Count > 0 Then
    Dim userName As String = Usuario.FirstOrDefault().ID.ToString()
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, False)
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
End If
```